# Match regex if not preceeded by certain words

Tags: php, regex

**Update : Actually php does not support lookbehind with variable lengths. This approach is not possible in php. Any variable length lookbehind will give an error "Compilation failed: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length"**

I have the following regex (i'm using php) :

```
/\d{2}\s\b(ans|year|years|sana|años|anos|sna)\b/i
```

that matches patterns like :

```
22 years
49 ans
98 anos
```

I need to cause it to not match if the input is preceeded by certain words ("since", "depuis", etc)

so :

```
I'm 22 years
I have 49 years
```

**would match**, while :

```
Since 19 years
Depuis 10 ans
```

**would not match**.

I've tried this, to no effect :

```
/(?<!(depuis|since|monz))\d{2}\s\b(ans|year|years|sana|años|anos|sna)\b/i
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a space between `since` and `19` in your text, but not in your expression. You probably want to add it.

Comment: Are you using a specific programming language?

Comment: @ Fernando, php - updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lookbehind is not well formed. The "or" conditon in lookbehinds (when used inside parens in PHP) requires same length. Otherwise you can just write the whole lookbehind conditions one by one like in

```
$str = "I'm 22 years and I have 49 years but Since 19 years and Depuis 10 ans";
preg_match_all(
'~
    (?<!
        \bdepuis\s  |
        \bsince\s   |
        \bmonz\s
    )
    \d{2}\s
    (?:
        ans?    |
        years?  |
        sana    |
        años?   |
        anos?   |
        sna
    )\b
~xi',$str,$m);
print_r($m);
```

### [EDIT 2]

There's a chance that there might be multiple empty spaces between the last word and the desired part (like [@nhahtdh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1400768/nhahtdh) wrote below in the comments). Although this is not a single pattern here's how you can avoid such situations.

```
$pat =
'~
    (
        (?(?<=^)(?=\s*)             # if it is the beginning of the string
            (?:\s*)                 # match possible spaces
            |                       # otherwise match
            (?:
                (?<=\s)             # following a space,
                (?:                 # a word that is not listed below
                    (?!(?:
                        depuis  |
                        since   |
                        monz
                    ))
                    \S
                )+
                \s+                 # and 1 or more spaces
            )
        )
    )
    \d{2}\s+                        # then your pattern itself
    (?:
        ans?    |
        years?  |
        sana    |
        años?   |
        anos?   |
        sna
    )\b
~xi';
preg_match_all($pat,$str,$matches);
foreach ($matches[0] as $k => &$v)
    // replace the previous word if any
    $v = substr($v,strlen($matches[1][$k]));
// and delete the reference
unset($v);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: There is a catch when using this solution: consecutive space characters should be replaced with 1 space character.

Comment: @nhahtdh What do you mean?

Comment: If the input is `Since_____19_years` (`_` stands for space), then the regex will match 19 years, when it shouldn't. There is no way around this for PHP regex, as far as I know.

Comment: Unless the OP has no problem having optional white spaces in the match. Then `\s` can be copied outside the lookbehind (as `\s*`).

Comment: You can try to think of a way to prevent the case I pointed out from matching. I can't find a way to do so with PHP regex (space outside or inside). If you cannot find a way, then you should update your post with the caveat.

Comment: @nhahtdh You're right. I edited my answer. Thanks for pointing that out. I wish we could trick the parser for lookbehinds like in `(?<!etc(?=\s+))`

Comment: You can simply replace `\s+` with `\s` or `_+` with `_` (`_` is space). I don't think whitespace characters is significant here.

Comment: @nhahtdh You're right about `\s+` although, only the one in the if condition can be replaced by `\s`. I don't understand what you mean by the other whitespace characters. Does that have anything to do with the code I posted?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23497/discussion-between-nhahtdh-and-inhan)

Comment: @SherifBuzz Sorry it's a bit long, though, but I couldn't find any other way with a single pattern, the flavor of which requires specified lengths in lookbehind subgroups.