# Regex to match strings not preceded by another string

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, contains, inverse

I have a large xml file open in VS Code that I would like to search for the word "street" not preceded by "PO box".

I found this example: [Match regex if not preceeded by certain words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14553604/match-regex-if-not-preceeded-by-certain-words)

But VS Code says the string I came up with isn't valid:

```
~(?<!\bbox\s)\d{2}\s(?:street)\b~xi
```

Comment: Are you searching in files? Note that this is wrong syntax, you should be using `\b(?<!\bPO box\s+)street\b` or something like that (with case insensitive option on in VSCode settings) if you are using the infile search and replace feature.

Comment: I'm searching in  a specific file that I have open in VSCode.

Comment: If you want a real solution, please provide example text and expected result/behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this one will help you:

```
(?<!PO box )street
```

Basically, it searches the word "street" and then checks if "PO box" is not behind it ([negative lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html))

[Working example](https://regex101.com/r/36U8XX/1).

Tested in VSCode too and looks like it is working.

Comment: When I try:

`(?<!po box ) street`

I get this in VS code:

`Invalid regular expression: /(?<!po
box ) street/: Invalid group `

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by Ariel is valid.

Regarding the issue Eric was having with VS Code, lookbehind regex was not supported by VS Code at the time [(reference)](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/63482).

Since VS Code version 1.31, lookbehind regex is supported in the file editor search [(reference)](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/68004).

Note that lookbehind regex is still not supported in the 'Find in Files' (Magnifying Glass) search [(reference)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/143453#issuecomment-1048139108).

Comment: Lookbehinds are supported in the Find in Files, but just not non-fixed length lookbehinds.  That is what your reference link says and you can test it yourself.